# When should I explicitly call 'close()' on a socket in Python?

Tags: sockets, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a very simple Python 2.7 function to listen for a socket connection on a localhost port.

Question is: If something bad happens when is my code responsible for killing the socket so that is not left dangling out there? In what cases will a socket error close the socket for me so that I don't need to call 'close()'?

I want to avoid having to start my testing all over with a different port because the old one was left open.

Python code sample:

```
def getconn(PORT,TIMEOUT_SECS):
     conn = ''
     try:
         HOST = ''
         s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
         s1.settimeout(TIMEOUT_SECS)
         s1.bind((HOST, PORT))
         s1.listen(1)
         conn, addr = s1.accept()
         print('Connected by', addr)
    except socket.timeout as e:
         conn = 'socket timeout'
    except socket.error as e:
         conn = 'other socket error'
    except:
         conn = 'deaddead'
         if s1:
              s1.close()
    return conn
```

And used here (say PORT argument is 19111)...

```
def runtest01_normalpoll(PORT):
     conn = getconn(PORT, 10.0)
     if conn == 'socket timeout' or conn == 'other socket error' or conn == 'deaddead':
          print 'could not establish a connection...why you ask?', conn
     else:
          conn.close()
     print 'done...'
```

It seems to work but am I missing any edge cases that would leave the socket open or cause anything else bad to happen?